# How to inject a variable in threadlocal in spring integration flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I need to inject a callContext object as thread Local in spring integration flow. A traceId which is received in jms header should be extracted n set in the callContext object so that it gets printed in log which is configured at project level.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination(topicName))
.log(INFO, m-> “message received for: + ((Order)m.getPayload()).getOrderId())
.handle(orderService)
.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it in your `orderService`, or add another service just before it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a `Function` for `log()` operator provides you full control over what you would like to log in the message. Of course, also avoiding overhead with the `ThreadLocal`. But if you still would like to use it, I would suggest a `.wireTap()` before that `log()`, so you can store a value in your `ThreadLocal` (MDC?) without effecting the main flow.

Only the problem that you have to remember to clean that `callContext` somehow to avoid thread local pollution.